# Round Robin Case Queues

Tags: case, queue

We have a onshore queue, it should automatically get routed to one of the Pods queue through a round robin basis. We have Pod 1, Pod 2, Pod 3, Pod 4. Need to distribute cases evenly through round robin

help me please

Comment: Did you check Omni Channel?

Comment: Not yet please tell me how to do this through Omni Channel?

Comment: Refer https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/omni-channel-lex

Comment: this is not the right solution i wanna round robin this. I have cases in a queue name On Shore Queue. I have to distribute these cases to another queues automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using case assignment rules easily.

Create a trigger to set a number/text field populated incrementally using a custom setting where you can maintain a number sequence. Add your logic to fill field only if the owner criterion is met.

Logic should be assign numbers 1,2,3...x and then reset the value in a custom setting.

Create assignment rules to use this new field and perform the assignment.

Refer this similar lead assignment example with additional details and pictures.

[Round Robin Lead Assignment](https://www.shellblack.com/administration/create-a-round-robin-lead-or-case-assignment-rule/)

Alternatively, you can do the assignment to the queues directly in the triggers itself instead of assigning the numbers and using assignment rules.

Let me know if you need help with pseudocode.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But i have a different problem, i have a queue where i have cases assigned to the queue. I wanna distribute these cases to another queues.How can i achieved this bro?

Comment: When a case gets submitted to the onshore queue, it should automatically get routed to one of the Pods queue through a round robin basis.

Comment: In that case, you want to generate this auto-number only for those records which get assigned to the incoming queue. I mean you can get this number which queue it should go depend on a static value picked up from custom setting.

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: i have 1 more thing to do i'm getting stuck in.

Comment: We want our customers to submit issues via email, for now.
If I split up the country into multiple support teams, and each of these teams wants to have their own Case Queue, would it be a best practice to use the email address to which the email address is sent as the assignment rule criteria?

- Eastern - customers send email to XXXEast@abc.com, assign to East queue
- Western - customers send email to XXXWest@abc.com, assign to west queue
- Northern - customers send email to XXXNorth@abc.com, assign to north queue
etc.

Comment: This is a new problem you are facing and it would be great if you can post a new question and mark this one as solved by choosing the best answer.